# Impersonation on windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7, impersonation

I've been working on some application that copy files trough a local domain. When I try to copy files with the application on windows XP with an account with absolutely no right which is impersonating an account with all right, everything is done perfectly. But, when I take the same account wich is impersonating the same account as above on windows 7 the application return "access denied" on the first line

I took the same snippet code on [Impersonate msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx) but here's mine with the fileSeeker function:

```
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out SafeTokenHandle phToken);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    // Test harness. 
    // If you incorporate this code into a DLL, be sure to demand FullTrust.
    [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]

    public impersonateSetting(string userName, string domainName, string password, string pathToSeek)
    {
        SafeTokenHandle safeTokenHandle;
        try
        {

            const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
            //This parameter causes LogonUser to create a primary token. 
            const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;

            // Call LogonUser to obtain a handle to an access token. 
            bool returnValue = LogonUser(userName, domainName, password,
                LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                out safeTokenHandle);

            Console.WriteLine("LogonUser called.");

            if (false == returnValue)
            {
                int ret = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                Console.WriteLine("LogonUser failed with error code : {0}", ret);
                throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(ret);
            }
            using (safeTokenHandle)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Did LogonUser Succeed? " + (returnValue ? "Yes" : "No"));
                Console.WriteLine("Value of Windows NT token: " + safeTokenHandle);

                // Check the identity.
                Console.WriteLine("Before impersonation: "
                    + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
                // Use the token handle returned by LogonUser. 
                using (WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(safeTokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle()))
                {
                    using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate())
                    {

                        // Check the identity.
                        Console.WriteLine("After impersonation: "
                            + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

                        fileRunner.fileSeeker(pathToSeek, true);

                    }
                }
                // Releasing the context object stops the impersonation 
                // Check the identity.
                Console.WriteLine("After closing the context: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred. " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

public sealed class SafeTokenHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
{
    private SafeTokenHandle()
        : base(true)
    {
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        return CloseHandle(handle);
    }
```

fileSeeker function:

```
    public static void fileSeeker(string paramFrom, bool copySub)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(paramFrom);
        DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

        try
        {
            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                    string temppath = Path.Combine(paramFrom, file.Name);
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Accessing: " + temppath);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Cant Access to " + temppath);
                    }
            }

            if (copySub)
            {
                foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
                {
                    string temppath = Path.Combine(paramFrom, subdir.Name);

                    fileSeeker(subdir.FullName, copySub);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: where does it fail exactly, first line here `DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(paramFrom);` or is it elsewhere?

Comment: Actually it doesn't fail at all.. accessing to file from a session who doesn't have access with impersation of an account who can acces have an access denied on win7. But yeah, it shoot access denied to this line

Answer (score 0):

If it's failing here, `FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();`, chances are the account you impersonated doesn't have permission to the `dir` path on the Win7 machine where this is running, make sure that this account has access to the source path first, the impersonation code seems fine

Comment: But normally the users don't have access to this file but I want them to be able to copy those files from computerA to computerB from computerC with an administrator account without they know the password of it

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeLépine right, what I meant is, is it possible that the account you are impersonating (the "admin account") does not have access to whichever path `dir` is pointing at?

Comment: Actually, with the administrator account, we can easily access to these folders and files with "\\computerName\C$\etc.." but when I'm trying to use the impersonate with the application we get an access denied and it only happens on windows 7 . The users dont have access to them.